# how many characters should wc -c actually return under FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, wc

In FreeBSD 10.2 , I want to experiment with "wc -c".

I created the file su.c in which I typed "hello , Jack." - only 13 characters.

I didn't type the enter key - there is only one line.

Why wc -c tells me there are 14 characterss ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHeh9RnZNms

I have just used

```
od -bc su.c
```

and got 
[image]

which surprised me with one '\n' at the end.  I never used the newline. Why it appears?

Answer (score 0):

It appears because whatever method you used to create the file (`echo`? `cat`?) added it. This is not a `wc` problem, it's just a consequence of how you created the file.

If you want tighter control over those characters, use [`printf(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%205.0-RELEASE) to create the source file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you created the file, but some text editors automatically make sure each file ends with a newline.  Echo also adds a newline if you don't give it the -n option.  You can see the difference:

```
$ echo abcd | wc -c
       5
$ echo -n abcd | wc -c
       4
```